# Android Dynamic Feature module - How can i access class, fragment and all resources

Tags: android

How to access dynamic feature module class,fragment and it's function?, I need to access all module file and main app file both accessbile so its possbile?

for example DynamicFeature(Module) has fragment and class so i need to access in main project
and also call main to DynamicFeature